# Show Preview of .psd files in Windows 7's Explorer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows

I was wondering if there is a way to view a preview in the icon of the photoshop files in windows 7(simmilar to the preview of a jpeg file for example) instead of the photoshop file default blue icon.

I guess the only way is to use Adobe Bridge isn't it ?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Windows 64bit version

Answer (score 24):

There is a project called [SageThumbs](http://www.cherubicsoft.com/en/projects/sagethumbs). It's A Windows Explorer extension allowing to preview many image formats:

It's AWESOME! almost perfect :)

Comment: don't forget to install ghostscript

Answer (score 5):

Windows is not able to show PSD thumbnails by default.

However, I managed get it working with using a DLL file.

Mind you that fiddling with DLL files is VERY dangerous. It may cause your computer to crash or even may damage your Windows installation altogether.

So please follow the tutorial if you are absolutely sure what you are doing and don't even try if you're not!

And apparently this will not work on 64bit computers.

http://www.techyard.net/enable-thumbnail-view-for-psd-files-in-windows-explorer/

Comment: great! I am on 64bit :)) so no sollution for me :). but thanks for this also :)

Comment: There could be a paid solution for you!

http://mysticcoder.net/mysticthumbs.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that works  for me -  Windows 7, 64bit, Photoshop CS2.
I downloaded an older Photoshop 7 free trial.  Both  7 and 8 are freely and legally available from many websites.
The trial doesn't even open on my windows 7 but by installing the older version, all the code to view psd thumbs on your computer is installed in the background. This Includes thumbs view in IE and Photoshop.
Here is a simple way to get thumbs to view after you install a free trial of PS: Begin by opening your files from your normal Photoshop and wait for all the psd's thumbs to view. Once all your thumbs are visible in all of your folders opened in Photoshop. IE will now recognizes them also.
Tip: If you use C Cleaner to clean your computer from time to time. Open C Cleaner, go to Applications/Windows explorer and un-tick Thumbnail Cache check box. Saves repeating the whole ordeal of re-opening thumbs in Photoshop after cleaning.
Even after the trial expires, Thumbs continue to work. The code is there.

Comment: Yeah. Older versions of Photoshop installed with a built-in thumbnail viewer in file manager but it was removed when they brought in Adobe Bridge. I remember being very pissed when I paid a couple of hundred dollars for the upgrade only to find I had lost a valuable feature! You could manually install the handler for a version or too but it was not updated for 64-bit.  To me, this was when Adobe "jumped the shark"!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone who runs PS under Windows, this app is a godsend for viewing not only PSD files, but all PS presets, inside and outside of Photoshop or Photoshop Elements. I've been using it for the last few years, and to me, it's indispensable. 
http://www.tumasoft.com/

[image]

Comment: And what is the advantage of that? In relation to the other named tools in the other questions? Is it free?  Do you work in that company?

Answer (score -1):

In Photoshop, if Image Previews is set to Always Save (under File Handling in Preferences), then Photoshop will generate a composite image of your document when it is saved. This is used to show a preview by OS X in QuickLook and other apps. It's quite likely Windows 7 is the same as OS X, and will require Image Previews to view the previews in Explorer.

However, if Image Previews is set to Never Save, then your PSDs will not contain previews and they won’t be able to be viewed by QuickLook, Preview, TextEdit or other OS X apps.

For the setting to take effect, you may have to save your document to a new location with Save As, rather than just using Save.

Saving image previews will make your PSDs bigger. Choose wisely.

Comment: My Image Previews under File Handling in Preferences is set to "Always save" ... so it isn't that .. :(

Comment: Maybe Windows Explorer can't preview Photoshop PSDs? I don't have enough experience with Windows to know if it does. Those tips definitely work for OS X though (I've done quite a bit of testing on the topic).

Comment: Windows used to support it natively but it no longer does.  I'm not sure if it was the switch to Vista and the new handling of previews?  Lots of problems in Windows Vista/7 with PDF previews as well.  [It seems that ADBE wants OS manufacturers to do the work themselves.  AAPL did, MSFT has not yet.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/why-cant-psd-thumbnails-be-displayed-in-windows-7/c898697e-3cca-41fc-b273-576042a904b1)

Comment: This answer does not provide useful info to a Windows user.